# What are the assumptions for porous media to be considered as continuum?

Tags: continuum-mechanics, models, porous-media

The poroelastic models like - Biot theory- are built on the continuum approach. But I am not able to understand, how this heterogeneous media can be considered as a continuum.

However, If the porous material is anisotropic and tortuous, I think we cannot apply the continuum approach to model the flow inside the porous media. If this is true, then how to model the same?

Answer (score 2):

You should use continuum mechanics laws and approaches based  on axiomatics of continuum mechanics:

1. Euclidean space. The space in which body motion is considered is
   three-dimensional
2. Absolute time $t$. The time does not
   depend on the choice of reference system.
3. Hypothesis of continuity. The material body is a continuous medium
4. The law of conservation of mass. Every material body $V$ has a
   scalar non-negative characteristic - mass $M$, which: a) does not
   change with any body movements if the body consists of the same
   material points, b) is an additive value: $M (V) = M (V_ {1}) + M
   (V_ {2})$, where $V = V_ {1} + V_ {2}$.
5. The law of conservation of momentum (change in the amount of
   motion).
6. The law of conservation of angular momentum (changes in angular
   momentum).
7. The law of conservation of energy (the first law of thermodynamics).
8. The existence of absolute temperature (the third law of
   thermodynamics).
9. The law of entropy balance (second law of thermodynamics).

Comment: Any reason for "Euclidean space" to appear twice?